# Is there any alternative to restarting app in iOS?

Tags: swift

I have a project which uses both English and Arabic. Once i select a language I need to reflect the changes immediately or make the app restart.

I change the language in settings page. I get the localised file from server and i save them locally and then use it.

And Also if you could give me hint to localize the storyboard it would be a great help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to provide the full context, show what you have achieved so far and ask a specific question. At the moment, it is unclear what "project uses both English and Arabic" means, where you select the language, what happens now and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: Is it not just possible to show the language depending on the devices settings? And thus use the standard localization system?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: When you say "settings page" you mean Apple's Settings app? Or a settings screen within your app? And you are writing that you get the localized file and use it. So what's the problem?

Comment: For localizing your storyboard look at this: https://izziswift.com/swift-localization-in-storyboard-labels-not-added-to-main-strings/ but for localizations fetched from the web this might not be the right solution.

Comment: Use "exit(0)" to restart the app.

Comment: There it might be needed to set each text in the coresponding viewController using the @IBOutlet var textView: TextContentType! and then setting its text in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

In general I think you don't want to restart the app, this is not something the user might expect, it might look like a crash.

If you are just starting a new project I would recommend you to revert what you have done and just use a SwiftUI Project for this, for you can do that there relatively easy.

You would set up an ObservableObject class that has an @Published dictionary containing all the string for the current language defined by their identifier. This class would be inserted in your UI as an EnvironmentVariable in the top of the UI, so that it can be accessed everywhere. For each place in your UI you want to put a text you get the right element from that dictionary with its identifier.
Once you fetch another language from the web, you just replace the dictionary with the new one from the web (I think, that dictionaries can be generated from json files, so that would even be a plus for web fetched localization). The way SwiftUI is made, it will redo your views automatically once this change is made and your app is in the right language automatically.